Spring boot better design responsibility
In my application, there are post, comment, vote entities.
I injected post service, comment service to verify the data to vote.
VoteService
@Transactional
public boolean votePost(Member currentMember, Long postId)
{
    Post post = postService.getPostById(postId);
    Optional<Vote> optionalVote = voteRepository.findByMemberAndPost(currentMember, post);

    if(optionalVote.isPresent())
    {
        voteRepository.delete(optionalVote.get());
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
       voteRepository.save(new Vote(currentMember, post));
       return true;
    }
}

and also I need vote service in post service and comment service to check the logged-in user's vote status.
VoteService
public boolean checkIfMemberVotedPost(Long memberId, Long postId)
{
    return voteRepository.existsVoteByMemberIdAndPostId(memberId, postId);
}

public boolean checkIfMemberVotedComment(Long memberId, Long commentId)
{
    return voteRepository.existsVoteByMemberIdAndCommentId(memberId, commentId);
}

But in this case, bean circular dependency error will occur.
I would like to know a better design or approach.
I know that using @Lazy can handle this problem but is this a valid solution instead of redesigning the application?

There's nothing wrong with using a circular dependency as long as you aren't creating circular logic, i.e. Service A calls Service B which calls Service A which calls Service B....
This is the primary reason why we should avoid circular dependencies, because as long as a circular dependency exists, circular logic possible. However that doesn't necessarily mean it's always bad. It just means you have to be more careful.
With that said, there are a bunch of ways you could redesign your application to fix this. For instance, instead of tightly coupling a Vote to a Post, you could make your voting system entity independent. In other words, you can add a "vote" to any "entity" and you would store the vote with an (EntityType, EntityID) key. In addition, you would have the votePost method flow through the PostService instead of the VoteService since the VoteService is now a generic voting mechanism, and the PostService would be responsible for voting on that entity specifically. This would remove the dependency on your PostService within VoteService, and it would also open up the possibility for a user to "vote" on other types of content. But this is just one solution to the problem.
Good luck!
